# What is the best route to parse rss feed, insert it into mysql db and then asynchronously acess with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, rss

Sorry, this is my first question. But i'm a relentless reader here.

So, i want to import the data from a rss feed, parse it into mysql (maybe using php?). Then i want to use ajax to load that info (example: image rss feed) into a container (example: slideshow).

So, will i have to use php to transfer info from the Rss feed to my mySQL DB. Then to have my data load without refreshing website (asynchronously), will i have to use jQuery?

I need some guidance in this area..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some sort of a server side language to access the database. Cannot do this from the browser. As for jquery - it should certainly make your life a bit easier, but it isn't a "must have". It will just take all the dirty work for handling and preparing ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you.
Yeah, i guess i'll have to use php with mysql and then ajax + jquery to retrieve the data.

Do you know of some resource materials for me to study?